# Is there any document/page explaining in detail how monotouch handles memory management / object lifetime of unmanaged (NSObject) objects

Tags: ios, memory-management, xamarin.ios

I've read the small section about Dispose() in http://monotouch.net/Documentation/API_Design and a similar question asked in monotouch forums before: http://forums.monotouch.net/yaf_postst136_Memory-Management-Questions.aspx . However, I'm still a bit confused about how things are really working under the covers.

I assume things work in a similar way to the .NET COM RCWs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973274.aspx), but I'm trying to make sure this is the case.

Knowing exactly how things work will help me answer questions like, for example, if I SetImage on a UIButton, am I now free to dispose the UIImage I just assigned, as the underlying UIKit button control will be the only thing using the native UIImage (and that the managed UIButton will not use the managed object I assigned in any way).

I will gladly contribute to the monotouch wiki myself once I understand how things work.

Comment: Tell you what: ask me the questions directly, and I will reply and update the docs accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to summarize the various issues here:

http://monotouch.net/Documentation/API_Design#Memory_Management

Please ask me any questions you want, and I will answer by extending the document.

Comment: Miguel, thanks much for the write up. I think one thing that I'm trying to get my head wrapped around is that it is indeed a bit harder to keep 'precise'. For example, in objective C/ref counted systems, when I assign Image to ImageView, I can just release image, as ImageView will hold a count. It is not really correct to Dispose Image after the assignment. To Dispose just after I don't need the image any more I would have to hold to Image until I'm done with ImageView, correct? I guess I brain farted here a bit, as it is probably not different in other managed frameworks.

Comment: not different in other managed frameworks and never thought about it twice, would just let framework finalize the resources and just realized this trying to troubleshoot leaks this time around.